# Uninstalled KDE-dependencies, can't install kile again

Tags: 11.04, kde, kile

## ubuntu 11.04

Hi everybody,

This morning I was running a little bit short on HDD space and had the bright idea to uninstall all those weird KDE-related libraries I had installed. Turns out, I should have thought that through better, since it literally killed my kile.

I tried recovering it, either by synaptic, ubuntu software center or apt-get, but I always get dependency problems, like this one:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:  kile : Depends:
>   kdebase-runtime but it is not going to be installed
>           Depends: konsole but it is not going to be installed E: Broken packages

Easy, I thought, sudo apt-get of each of those components, but turns out it doesn't work. After half an hour trying to install things, I just give up and hope for your help, any insight :)?

Cheers,

Answer (score 2):

After browsing around like crazy, I found a definitive solution, just in case someone comes up with the same problem I had. The solution consists of installing aptitude and then installing kile through aptitude:

Following the commands

```
    sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

and

```
    sudo aptitude -R install kdebase-runtime
    sudo aptitude -R install konsole        
    sudo aptitude -R install kile
```